# Conditionally display an item property on view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

New to ASP.NET MVC 3.  This seems like it should be a really simple issue, but it's actually got me stumped.  What I want to do is display a certain DateTime value if a value has been entered, or leave the space empty if no value has been entered.  The code in my view is simply this:

```
<td>
  @if (item.TimeReturned > DateTime.MinValue) 
  { 
    Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeReturned); 
  }
</td>
```

which seems really basic and straightforward.  Also, though it seems like overkill, `TimeReturned` explicitly defaults in the model to `DateTime.MinValue`.

No values are ever displayed.  Just to make sure it wasn't some operator funkiness, I also tried

```
<td>
  @if (DateTime.Compare(item.TimeReturned,DateTime.MinValue) != 0) 
  { 
    Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeReturned ); 
  }
</td>
```

which also displays nothing.  I must be missing some fundamental insight.  I could write a method in the model class to accomplish this, I guess, but it seems intuitive to do it this way.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post the controller code that is populating TimeReturned. Also, you should probably use a Nullable DateTime instead of DateTime.MinValue. Then you can just check if item.TimeReturned != null

Comment: This seems like a c# datetime comparison issue, and not an asp.net mvc 3 issue. If you had setup `@if(true){Html.DisplayFor(...);}` it would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
<td>
  @if (item.TimeReturned > DateTime.MinValue) 
  { 
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeReturned) 
  }
</td>
```

Comment: For anyone who encounters this in the future: I thought that `@if...{` would make a single Razor block that did not require another `@` - like `@{`.  This is wrong; the `{` starts a **text** block that will be interpreted as html, so another `@` is required before any C# statements within.  Thanks to all who replied!

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as follows

```
       @if (condetion)
        {
            @:@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.property)
        }
```